# Run Powershell script with C#, Exceptions

Tags: c#, powershell

I am trying to run a powershell script and I have tried two different approaches but get exceptions from both. What code do I need to add or what do I need to change?

Inside the script am I trying to add a parameter;

```
Param([string]$MainDoc="not")
```

First approch with Pipeline() and Command():

```
public static void RunPowerShell(string filePath, string parameterValue, string parameterName)
        {

            try
            {

                Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
                runspace.Open();

                RunspaceInvoke runSpaceInvoker = new RunspaceInvoke(runspace);
                runSpaceInvoker.Invoke("Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted");

                Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
                Command command = new Command(filePath);

                CommandParameter argParam = new CommandParameter(parameterName, parameterValue);
                command.Parameters.Add(argParam);

                pipeline.Commands.Add(command);

                pipeline.Invoke();
                runspace.Close();

            }catch(Exception e){

                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.GetBaseException());

            }
        }
```

Exception from this code:

```
System.Management.Automation.Host.HostException: Cannot invoke this function because the current host does not implement it.
   at System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHostRawUserInterface.ThrowNotInteractive()
   at System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHostRawUserInterface.get_ForegroundColor()
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConsoleColorCmdlet.get_ForegroundColor()
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteHostCommand.PrintObject(Object o)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteHostCommand.PrintObject(Object o)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteHostCommand.ProcessRecord()
   at System.Management.Automation.Cmdlet.DoProcessRecord()
   at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()
```

Second approach with Process():

```
public static void RunPowerShell(string filePath, string parameterValue, string parameterName)
        {

            try
            {

                Process p = new Process();

                p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

                p.StartInfo.FileName = filePath;
                p.StartInfo.Arguments = " -" + parameterName + " " + parameterValue;

                p.Start();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.GetBaseException());

            }
        }
```

This code gives exception:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
```

Which I just can not understand since it should be valid for my OS platform.

What have I missed and what should I change? This should be a simple task, just running one Powershell with one argument.

Thnx in advance

Comment: Have you tried switching from AnyCPU to x86 or 64bit and see if it runs?

Comment: Maybe this can help you:  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kebab/2014/04/28/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c/

Comment: What does `filePath` contain in the second approach. If it is a script name, set `UseShellExecute` to true, or preface it with PowerShell.exe.

Comment: Thanks for the help! First of all I checked the target and it was already x86. Then I removed the first approch as a possible solution since I realised the target machine did not have powershell 2.0 installed and System.Management.Automation requires Powershell 2.0. After this I changed "UseShellExecute" to true but this only opened the Powershell script in the text editor. Instead I prefaced it with Powershell.exe and then it worked. Will update an answer with the solution for other users.

Answer (score 0):

The answer that helped were to preface it with Powershell.exe as the code below. filePath contains the path to the powershell script and the parameterValue contains the value for the powershell scripts parameter.

```
public static void RunPowerShell(string filePath, string parameterValue)
            {

                try
                {

                    Process.Start("C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\Powershell.exe", "" + filePath + " '" + parameterValue + "'");

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {

                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.GetBaseException());

                }
            }
```